# ¿Como incorporar un paginado de tabla en Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, html-tabla, paginación

Estoy en proceso de aprendizaje con este framework ([vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js)) y necesito encontrar la forma de agregar un paginado en una tabla, por el cual, este debe ampliarse a medida que mas objetos se agreguen y posteriormente listarlos en la tabla y que limite el número de items a mostrar por pestaña.

la tabla utilizada es la siguiente.

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Título</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Categoría</th>
      <th>Fecha creación</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr :key="post.IDEN_PUBLICACION" v-for="post in posts" v-if="!post.FLAG_VALIDADO && !post.FLAG_BAN">
      <td>{{post.NOMB_PUBLICACION}}</td>
      <td>{{post.CODI_TIPO_PUBLICACION == 'P' ? 'Producto' : 'Servicio' }}</td>
      <td>{{post.categoria.NOMB_CATEGORIA}}</td>
      <td>{{post.FECH_CREACION | dateFormat}}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success" @click="acceptPost(post)" title="Aceptar"><icon name="check"></icon></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" @click="ban(post)" title="Rechazar"><icon name="times"></icon></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Buscando, encontré que existen plugins que pueden ayudar en esta ocasión, pero si bien logro implementarlo visualmente, no se como empezar a desarrollar la conducta que necesito.

Intento con 'vue-paginate'.

```
<!--Paginación de tabla -->
  <template>
    <paginate
      :page-count="5"
      :page-range="1"
      :margin-pages="1"
      :click-handler="recorrerTabla"
      :prev-text="'Anterior'"
      :next-text="'Siguiente'"
      :container-class="'pagination'"
      :page-class="'page-item'">
    </paginate>
  </template>
```

Método:

```
methods: {
  acceptPost (post) {
  controller.acceptPost(this, post)
},
recorrerTabla: function (pageNum) {
  console.log(pageNum)
},
```

En resumen necesito, si bien usando vue-paginate o algún otro método alternativo, que el paginado me permita recorra los items totales de la tabla, pero divididos por pestañas de 5 items y de ser posible, que el número de paginas se acomode al total de items (Ej: items totales:15, el paginado muestra 3 pestañas para recorrer).

Imagen desde la vista
[image: Tabla + vue-paginate]

Tecnologías usadas:

*- Vuejs 2.4

 - Node 8+

 - Nuxt 1.0.0 - RC11

 - Nuxt/Axios 4.5.0

 - JWT-Decode 2.2.0

 - Js-Cookie

 - Vee-Validate*

De antemano, gracias por sus respuestas y cualquier documentación o ejemplo de ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tengas mayor suerte con las respuestas la proxima vez, evita el uso de capturas de pantalla del editor de texto / ide, ya que duplica el trabajo de la persona que intente ayudarte, por lo que te quita muchas posibilidades de que tu duda sea resuelta

Comment: gracias por el consejo.